Fill selected cells of pandas dataframe with the previous not null values in found in the dataset
I have a dataset like this one:



A
B




x
a


x
nan


y
c


z
d



Let’s say I want to change the last two rows and replace the values with the previous not nan values in the same column to get this dataset:



A
B




x
a


x
nan


x
a


x
a



How can I obtain this?

What if there are two nans in a row?

And what if you have other NaNs later on?

You can create a series that groups the last item before an NA value through the next time a value sits before an NA. Then perform a groupby operation using the series and transform each group to have the first value.  However, you need to replace the grouping ids before the first NA with something other than 0 so they are all not grouped together.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':list('xxyzwetqyw'), 
    'B':[*list('aba'), pd.NA, *list('cd'), pd.NA, *list('iip')]
})

g = df.isna().any(axis=1).cumsum().shift(-1).ffill()
g[g.eq(0)] += list(range(-g.eq(0).sum(),0))
df.groupby(g).transform('first')

This takes the original data frame:
   A     B
0  x     a
1  x     b
2  y     a    <- value above NA
3  z  <NA> 
4  w     c
5  e     d    <- value above NA
6  t  <NA>
7  q     i
8  y     i
9  w     p

and transforms it to:
   A  B
0  x  a
1  x  b
2  y  a    <- value above NA
3  y  a
4  y  a
5  e  d    <- value above NA
6  e  d
7  e  d
8  e  d
9  e  d


Assuming @Jame's example with multiple NaNs, you could create a mask with isna and shift, then mask the desired values with where and ffill, finally restore the leading values with fillna
m = df['B'].isna().shift(-1, fill_value=False)
out = df.where(m).ffill().fillna(df)

Variant without fillna:
m = df['B'].isna().shift(-1, fill_value=False)
out = df.where(m | ~m.cummax()).ffill()

Output:
   A  B
0  x  a
1  x  b
2  y  a
3  y  a
4  y  a
5  e  d
6  e  d
7  e  d
8  e  d
9  e  d

Used input (credit to @James for the nice example):
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':list('xxyzwetqyw'), 
    'B':[*list('aba'), pd.NA, *list('cd'), pd.NA, *list('iip')]
})

